# xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms" this is could not find

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Step 1:   Create New PCL Project

Step 2:   Adding Xlabs forms dll from nuget package manager  (Version :2.0.5782)

Step 3: Then i added  in mainpage.xaml file this below  code

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
             x:Class="App2.MainPage">
 <StackLayout>
        <controls:WrapLayout></controls:WrapLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App3
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Step 4: then run this project in uwp

[image: 1]

Step 5: I got this error

If any one have any idea please help me ........

Comment: no picture, no error is visible in your question. BTW, XLabs is deprecated

Comment: hi @YuriS i attached that exception in step 4 . it is run time exception . while running the application (Note: Enable the exception in visual studio) now you can see that error.

Comment: the error is clear. wraplayout is not in the XLabs.Forms.Controls namespace.  use object explorer to see what namespace of wraplayout if it even exists in xlabs. As I said I wouldn't use xlabs at all. it's gone

Comment: ok Thank you @YuriS . but i refered wrap panel  is exist in xlabs package. Another system i checked  it is working fine . My system only i am facing this issue

Comment: then compare what is the difference between systems where it is working and yours. did you install xlabs on all platforms?

Comment: Thanks .  for your  help @YuriS

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it (I think it is not a correct way) but i found problem. it is dll not initialize at application loading time . so i tried this below code.

I tried to initialize my XLab dll at  before initializeComponent() .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XLabs.Forms.Controls;

namespace App3
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            WrapLayout wp = new WrapLayout();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```